# Whitelist IP not working

Tags: php

Here's my code:

```
<?php

$whitelist = "61.4.121.157" or "43.4.521.32";   
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

if ($ip == $whitelist) {
echo "You can access the whitelist page!";
} else {
echo "Bad IP";
}
?>
```

I'm trying to make it so if you have 61.4.121.157 or 43.4.521.32 as an IP address, you can be greeted with "You can access the whitelist page!". But, It's only showing this page for the 61 IP. The 43 IP has "Bad IP". Please help!

Comment: this is not mysql... assign these ip to an array and use php `in_array()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure your syntax is valid, but you should use `in_array()`:

```
$whitelist = array("61.4.121.157", "43.4.521.32");   
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

if (in_array($ip, $whitelist)) {
    echo "You can access the whitelist page!";
} else {
    echo "Bad IP";
}
```

Comment: It's valid, but won't do anything like what is intended :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `or` operator in a way that does not make sense here. That operator only assigns exactly one address to your variable `$ip`, in this case only the first address.

Try this instead:

```
<?php

$whitelist = ["61.4.121.157", "43.4.521.32"];   
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

if (in_array($ip, $whitelist)) {
    echo "You can access the whitelist page!";
} else {
    echo "Bad IP";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the definition of `$whitelist`.
The `or` operator used this way says take the value at my left if it evaluate at true, else take the other one if it evaluate at true, else false.

What you need is an array:

```
$whitelist = array("61.4.121.157", "43.4.521.32");
```

And use the function `in_array` in you test.